# is there a way to get Socially signed in user from Servlet request using Stormpath?

Tags: java, google-signin, stormpath

Using stormpath web login, once a User has been authenticated, the currently logged in user Account is available on subsequent requests and can be retrieved by doing the following *(e.g from within a Servlet)* ;

```
Account account = AccountResolver.INSTANCE.getAccount(request);
```

*where `request` is `HttpServletRequest`*

Now, what i need to know is, why is it not possible to do the same thing for a socially signed in user (i.e a user that signs in with google, facebook, linked-in)???

I know that ***on sign-up/sign-in***, the Account can be retrieved by doing the following;

```
String applicationHref = appHref;
String code = request.getParameter("code");

Application application = client.getResource(appHref, Application.class);
ProviderAccountRequest request = Providers.GOOGLE.account()
            .setCode(code)
            .build();

ProviderAccountResult result = application.getAccount(request);
Account account = result.getAccount();
```

But afterwards, doing `Account account = AccountResolver.INSTANCE.getAccount(request);` always returns `null`.

Now this is a problem because `code` is only available on sign in and not for subsequent requests hence using the snippet above is not possible. Besides, it seems like too much work for everytime the currently loggedin Account has to be fetched.

I've endlessly browsed the Stormpath documentation and found no leads... Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet plugin has not support for social accounts yet. When you login with the Form then the Servlet is aware of that and puts the retrieved account in a cookie for later use. However, in the case of Social Logins, the servlet plugin is not yet aware of the Social Account Stores. I have just created [this issues](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/issues/399), you can subscribe to it in order to get notified about any progress of this feature.

It is relevant to mention that [IDSite](https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/008_idsite.html) does actually support Social Account Stores. In your Spring/SpringBoot app you only need to do this in order to use it:

```
stormpath.web.idSite.enabled = true
```

When you enable it, you will be using Login/Registration/Forgot/etc pages from IDSite rather than the locally available ones.